# How do I mock these classes using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please can someone show me how to properly mock this repository class. Basically I want to just mock out it so that I can easily test my services layer. Am moq using c# moq in my test project. Where am mostly having problems is in the virtual interface pattern used in the Query, Filter, Include and OrderBy methods. How do I mock it so that it can return the properly RepositoryQuery that I injected into my Repository mock.

The code shown below is part of my database layer that communicates with the database, so I want to mock it out so that I can easily test my services layer without external dependence to worry about.

```
 public sealed class RepositoryQuery<TEntity> : IRepositoryQuery<TEntity> where TEntity  : BaseEntity
   {

        private readonly List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> _includeProperties;
        private readonly Repository<TEntity> _repository;
        private readonly List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> _filters;
        private Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> _orderByQuerable;
        private int? _page;
        private int? _pageSize;

        public RepositoryQuery(Repository<TEntity> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _includeProperties = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();
            _filters = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
        }

        public RepositoryQuery<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            _filters.Add(filter);
            return this;
        }

        public RepositoryQuery<TEntity> OrderBy(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy)
        {
            _orderByQuerable = orderBy;
            return this;
        }

        public RepositoryQuery<TEntity> Include(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> expression)
        {
            _includeProperties.Add(expression);
            return this;
        }    

        public IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
        {
            return _repository.Get(_filters, _orderByQuerable, _includeProperties, _page, _pageSize);
        }

    }
```

and this

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
         private readonly Guid _instanceId;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
        private readonly IDbContext _context; 

        public Repository(IDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
            _instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public virtual IRepositoryQuery<TEntity> Query()
        {
            var repositoryGetFluentHelper = new RepositoryQuery<TEntity>(this);
            return repositoryGetFluentHelper;
        }

        internal IQueryable<TEntity> Get(
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> filters = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includeProperties = null,
            int? page = null,
            int? pageSize = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                includeProperties.ForEach(i => query = query.Include(i));
            }

            if (filters != null && filters.Any())
            {
                query = filters.Aggregate(query, (current, filter) => current.Where(filter));
            }

            query = orderBy != null ? orderBy(query) : query.OrderBy(a => a.Id);

            if (page != null && pageSize != null)
            {
                query = query
                    .Skip((page.Value - 1)*pageSize.Value)
                    .Take(pageSize.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What you mock is completely dependent on the test you're currently running. We cannot help you with that.. that is purely up to you. Look up basic mocking tutorials in order to see what people mock for each test. For example: you wouldn't mock out the entire Repository only to test one function.

Comment: Hi, some of the code above is what I used in my data layer, since it communicates with the data store, I want to entirely mock it out so that I can test not just one function but my entire services layer.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully your components depend on the interfaces `IRepositoryQuery<TEntity>` and `IRepository<TEntity>` and not the concrete implementations `RepositoryQuery<TEntity>` and `Repository<TEntity>`. If that is the case, then you provide test doubles for the interfaces for unit test purposes with Moq like so

```
var mockQuery = new Mock<IRepositoryQuery<TEntity>>();

// perform any setup needed on mockQuery for the particular System Under Test

var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<TEntity>>();

// perform any setup needed on mockRepository for the particular System Under Test

// component that relies on query and repository
// that is the System Under Test i.e. the focus of the unit test
var systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(mockRepository.Object, mockQuery.Object);
```

An observation; Looking at `RepositoryQuery<TEntity>`, I think the methods should return the interface `IRepositoryQuery<TEntity>` as opposed to the concrete implementation `RepositoryQuery<TEntity>`.

Comment: both of them have interfaces but the `RepositoryQuery<TEntity>` is tightly coupled to the `Repository<TEntity>` as it serves as a helper to the repository class, thats what gets me confused.

Comment: @Cizaphil what do the interfaces look like then?

Answer (score 1):

If `IRepositoryQuery` is the wrapper for `IRepository`, then - to test your service layer - you don't need to mock `IRepository`. Just mock `IRepositoryQuery`.

Assuming that I want to check that `SomeService.DoSomething` correctly processes the result it gets from `IRepositoryQuery.Get`:

```
var mock = new Mock<IRepositoryQuery<SomeClass>>();
mock.Setup(o => o.Get(/* test parameters */)).Returns(/* result */);

var myService = new SomeService(mock.Object);
Assert.That(myService.DoSomething(), Is.EqualTo(/* expected result*/));
```